# Gwt form question

Tags: gwt

I have a gwt form which has about 70-100 widgets (textboxes,listboxes,custom widgets etc)

I am trying to implement the features of CUT ,COPY in this form .For this i have  2 buttons right on top of the form.

Now the problem  i have is that when i click on the copy button , the widget that was focused in the form looses focus and i dont know which text to copy(or which widget was last focused before the focus getting to the copy button)

I was planning to implement blur handlers on all the widgets but i feel is a very laborious and not a good solution.

How can i get around this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps someone with a deeper insight might provide a better approach but I beleive adding blur handlers is perfectly valid. I do not quite see why you think it would be laborious, after all you don't need a different handler for each of your widgets, you can get away with only one(at most a couple for a variety of controls..), here is a very simple example,

```
public class CustomBlurHandler implements BlurHandler{
    Object lastSource;
    String text;    
    @Override
    public void onBlur(BlurEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() instanceof TextBox) {             
            lastSource = event.getSource();
            text = textBox.getSelectedText();
        }       
    }   
    public Object getLastSource() {
        return lastSource;
    }
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

and onModuleLoad :

```
public class Test implements EntryPoint {       
    CustomBlurHandler handler = new CustomBlurHandler();        
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        TextBox text1 = new TextBox();
        TextBox text2 = new TextBox();          
        text1.addBlurHandler(handler);
        text2.addBlurHandler(handler);      
        Button b = new Button("Get last selected text");
        b.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                Window.alert(handler.getLastSource()+ " " + handler.getText());
            }
        });
        RootPanel.get().add(text1);
        RootPanel.get().add(text2);
        RootPanel.get().add(b);         
    }   
}
```

Comment: I used your idea to an extent. Put in a static variable inside my widget and that would get updated whenever some text changes in the textbox. Put in getters and setter for that static text and that worked excellent!!!